# Aspx doesn't update DB from Repeater

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I've been working on making a an aspx site, and i've encountered something that just won't work in the way i want it to.

I have a Repeater i populate from a database. The repeater has a Literal and a Textbox for every cell. They're both populated with the same data, but the textbox is hidden as default. The textbox is only showe, and the Literal hidden when a user clicks an edit button.

This is all taken from this tutorial on editing a Repeater inline: [enter link description here](http://www.ajaxtutorials.com/general/using-repeater-to-edit-in-line-with-ajax-in-c/)

My problem though: I also have a done button (**doneBtn**), for when the user is done editing the row in the Repeater - this button works with a prepared statement in my database for updating a row with the new data from the repeater. It just doesn't work..

When i click edit the Literals are hidden and the textboxes are shown, but if i edit some of the text and click done, then nothing happens in the database. The textboxes are hidden and the literals are show again, but no data is being edited.

I can force it to "work" if i change every paramter value to a hard coded string in the C# code

```
SqlParameter doneActID = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ActivityID", SqlDbType.Int);
doneActID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
doneActID.Value = "Some String";
```

---

I included my C# code for the repeater editing and the prepared statement for good measure.

I hope someone can tell me what stupid thing i did wrong as i'm sure it'd something dumb, but I AM pretty new with proper coding (I'm all front-end), so go easy on me.

```
protected void RepeaterActivities_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        RepeaterItem item = e.Item;

        LinkButton crudEdit = (LinkButton)item.FindControl("crudEdit");
        LinkButton crudDelete = (LinkButton)item.FindControl("crudDelete");
        LinkButton crudDone = (LinkButton)item.FindControl("crudDone");
        LinkButton crudCancel = (LinkButton)item.FindControl("crudCancel");

        Literal LiteralID = (Literal)item.FindControl("LiteralID");
        TextBox TextBoxID = (TextBox)item.FindControl("TextBoxID");

        Literal LiteralTitle = (Literal)item.FindControl("LiteralTitle");
        TextBox TextBoxTitle = (TextBox)item.FindControl("TextBoxTitle");

        Literal LiteralDOTW = (Literal)item.FindControl("LiteralDOTW");
        TextBox TextBoxDOTW = (TextBox)item.FindControl("TextBoxDOTW");

        Literal LiteralTOTD = (Literal)item.FindControl("LiteralTOTD");
        TextBox TextBoxTOTD = (TextBox)item.FindControl("TextBoxTOTD");

        Literal LiteralDesc = (Literal)item.FindControl("LiteralDescription");
        TextBox TextBoxDesc = (TextBox)item.FindControl("TextBoxDescription");

        Literal LiteralRoom = (Literal)item.FindControl("LiteralRoom");
        TextBox TextBoxRoom = (TextBox)item.FindControl("TextBoxRoom");

        Literal LiteralImageUrl = (Literal)item.FindControl("LiteralImgUrl");
        Image ImageImgUrl = (Image)item.FindControl("ImageImgUrl");
        TextBox TextBoxImageUrl = (TextBox)item.FindControl("TextBoxImgUrl");

        Literal LiteralCoachID = (Literal)item.FindControl("LiteralCoachID");
        TextBox TextBoxCoachID = (TextBox)item.FindControl("TextBoxCoachID");

        if (e.CommandName == "editBtn")
        {
            crudEdit.Visible = false;
            crudDelete.Visible = false;
            crudDone.Visible = true;
            crudCancel.Visible = true;

            LiteralID.Visible = false;
            TextBoxID.Visible = true;

            LiteralTitle.Visible = false;
            TextBoxTitle.Visible = true;

            LiteralDOTW.Visible = false;
            TextBoxDOTW.Visible = true;

            LiteralTOTD.Visible = false;
            TextBoxTOTD.Visible = true;

            LiteralDesc.Visible = false;
            TextBoxDesc.Visible = true;

            LiteralRoom.Visible = false;
            TextBoxRoom.Visible = true;

            ImageImgUrl.Visible = false;
            LiteralImageUrl.Visible = false;
            TextBoxImageUrl.Visible = true;

            LiteralCoachID.Visible = false;
            TextBoxCoachID.Visible = true;
        }

        else if (e.CommandName == "deleteBtn")
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"data source = localhost; user = root; password = toor; database = dblocal");
            SqlCommand cmd = null;

            try
            {
                conn.Open();

                cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "delete";

                SqlParameter activityID = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ActivityID", SqlDbType.Int);
                activityID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                activityID.Value = LiteralID.Text;

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                showDataInTables();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Label1.Text = ex.Message;
            }

            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }

        else if (e.CommandName == "doneBtn")
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"data source = localhost; user = root; password = toor; database = dblocal");
            SqlCommand cmd = null;

            try
            {
                conn.Open();

                cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "update";

                SqlParameter doneActID = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ActivityID", SqlDbType.Int);
                doneActID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                doneActID.Value = TextBoxID.Text;

                SqlParameter doneActTitle = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Title", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
                doneActTitle.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                doneActTitle.Value = TextBoxTitle.Text;

                SqlParameter doneActDOTW = cmd.Parameters.Add("@DayOfTheWeek", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
                doneActDOTW.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                doneActDOTW.Value = TextBoxDOTW.Text;

                SqlParameter doneActTOTD = cmd.Parameters.Add("@TimeOfTheDay", SqlDbType.Time, 7);
                doneActTOTD.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                doneActTOTD.Value = TextBoxTOTD.Text;

                SqlParameter doneActDesc = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
                doneActDesc.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                doneActDesc.Value = TextBoxDesc.Text;

                SqlParameter doneActRoom = cmd.Parameters.Add("@RoomNumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
                doneActRoom.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                doneActRoom.Value = TextBoxRoom.Text;

                SqlParameter doneActImg = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ImgUrl", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
                doneActImg.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                doneActImg.Value = TextBoxImageUrl.Text;

                SqlParameter doneActCoachID = cmd.Parameters.Add("@CoachID", SqlDbType.Int);
                doneActCoachID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                doneActCoachID.Value = TextBoxCoachID.Text;

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                showDataInTables();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Label1.Text = ex.Message;
            }

            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }

        else if (e.CommandName == "cancelBtn")
        {
            crudEdit.Visible = true;
            crudDelete.Visible = true;
            crudDone.Visible = false;
            crudCancel.Visible = false;

            LiteralID.Visible = true;
            TextBoxID.Visible = false;

            LiteralTitle.Visible = true;
            TextBoxTitle.Visible = false;

            LiteralDOTW.Visible = true;
            TextBoxDOTW.Visible = false;

            LiteralTOTD.Visible = true;
            TextBoxTOTD.Visible = false;

            LiteralDesc.Visible = true;
            TextBoxDesc.Visible = false;

            LiteralRoom.Visible = true;
            TextBoxRoom.Visible = false;

            ImageImgUrl.Visible = true;
            LiteralImageUrl.Visible = true;
            TextBoxImageUrl.Visible = false;

            LiteralCoachID.Visible = true;
            TextBoxCoachID.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

---

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterActivities" runat="server" OnItemCommand="RepeaterActivities_ItemCommand">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <tr>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Day of the week</th>
            <th>Time of the day</th>
            <th class="th-description">Description</th>
            <th>Room Number</th>
            <th>Image URL</th>
            <th>Coach ID - FK</th>
        </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td class="crud-edit-delete">
                 <asp:LinkButton ID="crudEdit" runat="server" CommandName="editBtn" Text='<i class="material-icons">mode_edit</i>'></asp:LinkButton>
                 <asp:LinkButton ID="crudDelete" runat="server" CommandName="deleteBtn" Text='<i class="material-icons">delete</i>'></asp:LinkButton>
                 <asp:LinkButton ID="crudDone" runat="server" CommandName="doneBtn" Visible="false" Text='<i class="material-icons icon-done">done</i>'></asp:LinkButton>
                 <asp:LinkButton ID="crudCancel" runat="server" CommandName="cancelBtn" Visible="false" Text='<i class="material-icons">close</i>'></asp:LinkButton>
            </td>
            <td>
                 <asp:Literal ID="LiteralID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ActivityID") %>'></asp:Literal>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxID" CssClass="activity-id form-control" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ActivityID") %>' Visible="false" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                 <asp:Literal ID="LiteralTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>'></asp:Literal>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxTitle" CssClass="title form-control" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                 <asp:Literal ID="LiteralDOTW" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DayOfTheWeek") %>'></asp:Literal>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxDOTW" CssClass="dotw form-control" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DayOfTheWeek") %>' Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                 <asp:Literal ID="LiteralTOTD" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TimeOfTheDay").ToString().Substring(0, 5) %>'></asp:Literal>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxTOTD" CssClass="totd form-control" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TimeOfTheDay").ToString().Substring(0, 5) %>' Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                 <asp:Literal ID="LiteralDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>'></asp:Literal>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxDescription" CssClass="description form-control" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Literal ID="LiteralRoom" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RoomNumber") %>'></asp:Literal>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxRoom" CssClass="room form-control" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RoomNumber") %>' Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Image ID="ImageImgUrl" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "pictures/" + Eval("ImgUrl")%>' />
                <asp:Literal ID="LiteralImgUrl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ImgUrl") %>'></asp:Literal>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxImgUrl" CssClass="img-url form-control" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ImgUrl") %>' Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Literal ID="LiteralCoachID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CoachID_FK") %>'></asp:Literal>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxCoachID" CssClass="coach-id form-control" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CoachID_FK") %>' Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

---

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[update]
    @ActivityID int,
    @Title nvarchar(50),
    @DayOfTheWeek nvarchar(50),
    @TimeOfTheDay time(7),
    @Description nvarchar(255),
    @RoomNumber nvarchar(50),
    @ImgUrl nvarchar(50),
    @CoachID int
  AS
    UPDATE Activities
    SET Title = @Title, DayOfTheWeek = @DayOfTheWeek, TimeOfTheDay =  @TimeOfTheDay, Description = @Description, RoomNumber = @RoomNumber, ImgUrl = @ImgUrl, CoachID_FK = @CoachID
    WHERE ActivityID = @ActivityID;
  RETURN
```

Comment: Is the TextBoxId and others null when you hit the updateBtn?

Comment: If i throw in `Label1.Text = TextBoxID.Text + " " + TextBoxTitle.Text + " " + TextBoxDOTW.Text + " " + TextBoxTOTD.Text + " " + TextBoxDesc.Text + " " + TextBoxRoom.Text + " " + TextBoxImageUrl.Text + " " + TextBoxCoachID.Text; `
to see what happens with the textboxes it'll show the original text from the textbox and not my changes i just put in.

Comment: That's because the repeater is reading the DB on every page load. Refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx for page lifecycle. So basically your update method works, but the data on the textboxes is wrong.

Comment: Yeah okay, hmm. I have to be honest, I don't really have any idea where to go from here, though.

Comment: Post your repeater code. I can try. Takes a while though.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to use basic HTML controls instead of asp.net controls. They're somewhat easier to manage, and you can pull the content from form data. I'll show the relevant parts of code here, you'll get the idea.

aspx:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterActivities" runat="server" OnItemCommand="RepeaterActivities_ItemCommand">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <tr>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Day of the week</th>
            <th>Time of the day</th>
            <th class="th-description">Description</th>
            <th>Room Number</th>
            <th>Image URL</th>
            <th>Coach ID - FK</th>
        </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td class="crud-edit-delete">
                 <asp:LinkButton ID="crudEdit" runat="server" CommandName="editBtn" Text='<i class="material-icons">mode_edit</i>'></asp:LinkButton>
                 <asp:LinkButton ID="crudDelete" runat="server" CommandName="deleteBtn" Text='<i class="material-icons">delete</i>'></asp:LinkButton>
                 <asp:LinkButton ID="crudDone" runat="server" CommandName="doneBtn" Visible="false" Text='<i class="material-icons icon-done">done</i>'></asp:LinkButton>
                 <asp:LinkButton ID="crudCancel" runat="server" CommandName="cancelBtn" Visible="false" Text='<i class="material-icons">close</i>'></asp:LinkButton>
            </td>
            <td>
                 <label><%# Eval("ActivityID") %></label>
                 <input id="TextBoxID" runat="server" name="TextBoxID" visible="false" class="activity-id form-control" value='<%# Eval("ActivityID") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

aspx.cs:

```
protected void RepeaterActivities_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    // leave out the TextBox TextBoxID = (TextBox)item.FindControl("TextBoxID");
    // all your other code here...
    else if (e.CommandName == "doneBtn")
    {
        string id = Request.Form["TextBoxId"];

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"data source = localhost; user = root; password = toor; database = dblocal");
        SqlCommand cmd = null;

        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "update";

            SqlParameter doneActID = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ActivityID", SqlDbType.Int);
            doneActID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            doneActID.Value = id;

       // rest of your code...
```

What I did was that I replaced the `asp:TextBox` with a normal html `input` control. Remember to give it a `name` attribute so you can read the value from the form data on postback. Then on your code behind read the value and assign it to a string and use the string as the input parameter for your DB method.
Didn't test all of this, but it should work.

Comment: Thank you, Sami! With some modifications to accommodate for master pages screwing with things, that worked perfectly.